# Use Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups to show that subgroup is cyclic

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

my question was discussed in this thread:

[Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups and the mulitplicative group of a field.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471618/fundamental-theorem-of-finite-abelian-groups-and-the-mulitplicative-group-of-a-f)

I want to show that if G is a finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of an arbitrary field, then G is cyclic.

However, I don't really know what to do with the hint in the answer. It would be very nice if someone could go into more detail as to how to use that $x^k-1$ has at most $k$ roots in a field. What should $k$ be in this case? And how does the fundamental theorem come into play?

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is an Abelian group of order $n$, which is not cyclic, then it
has exponent $m$ with $m<n$. That is, $m\ge1$ and $a^m=1$ for all $a\in A$. This follows from the structure theorem for finite Abelian groups.

If $A$ is a subgroup of a multiplicative group of a field, then this
is impossible, since then $x^m-1=0$ has more than $m$ solutions.

Comment: Thank you. Does your first claim follow because if we have the group $\mathbb{Z} /n_1 \times \dots \times \mathbb{Z} /n_t$ where $n_1 | \dots |n_t$ then the exponent has to divide $n_t$. And thus the exponent must be smaller than $n$. Is that right? But what if $t=1$? Then $m<n$ would not necessarily follow.

Comment: The exponent is $n_t$. When $t=1$ the group is cyclic.